# Run script based on condition Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terraform

I have Jenkins recovery script which i would like to run on tfvar variable.

When tfvars set install_jennkins_fresh = false I would like to run the shell script on the remote resource.

I have some rough idea but I am not sure how can I put it together. I know I have to run null_resource with triggers and provisioners. But how can I fit in a variable where run shell script ONLY when  install_jennkins_fresh = false

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `var.install_jenkins_fresh` within the count parameter of a null resource executing the script.

When `install_jenkins_fresh` is set to `true` the local-exec provisioner will execute the [powershell] script.

```
resource "null_resource" "my_script" {
  count = var.install_jenkins_fresh ? 1 : 0

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo Hello"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to run this script on AWS instance which i have created.

Comment: `remote-exec` it is then: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/examples/terraform-remote-exec-example/main.tf